# Kickstart CentOS 7 with software RAID 1, but no LVM needed

Tags: partition, mdadm, kickstart, anaconda

I am going to Kickstart a CentOS 7.x installation with software RAID 1 remotely for the first time. So I am kinda inexperienced at this and wondering what I need to make this work correctly.

A CentOS 7.x kickstart with hardware raid, I use the following partition configuration:

```
# Disk partitioning information
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=1024
part / --fstype=ext4 --size=10000
part /vz --fstype=ext4vz --size=40768 --grow
part swap --size=4096
```

This works very well.

However since I have never ever done a software RAID 1 on CentOS in general, I am wondering what the correct commands are to do so? I did some searching, but most tutorials / information I found on Google is pretty dated or uses LVM (Volume Group), which I don't want.

I want the exact same thing as I have above, but this time with software RAID 1.

Can someone give me a workable example of how this can be done? And do I need to make changes as well to other aspects of my Kickstart configuration? E.g. bootloader configuration.

Oh and I don't use EFI. Don't know if that is important to mention.

Sorry for popping the question. I did search, but couldn't find any workable information and/or examples to experiement with. And as I said; I am doing this remotely and I don't have direct access (well unless I drive).

Thanks in advance!

//edit #1

I wanted to give it a go on a local test machine with 2x 120GB SSD's in software RAID 1. So I went through the CentOS 7.x installer by using this [tutorial](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-install-centos-rhel-7-on-raid-1-partition/) for the CentOS 7.x installation GUI.

Well after a wait, I rebooted and apparently it was setup correctly:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md127     ext4      9.5G  4.7G  4.4G  52% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  9.7M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md124     ext4       74G   53M   70G   1% /vz
/dev/md125     ext4      488M  149M  305M  33% /boot
tmpfs          tmpfs     379M  4.0K  379M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs          tmpfs     379M   48K  379M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs          tmpfs     379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
```

So since this was setup correctly I decided to take a peak at the anaconda-ks.cfg file. No partition scheme in there. Okay, so I checked the next file "initial-setup-ks.cfg". Same thing, no partition scheme. Sigh.

I always thought that your current setup, through the installer GUI, was reflected in those files? Wishful thinking apparently. So I am back to scratch again...

//edit #2

Nobody has an idea on how to do this correctly? :(

Comment: I tend to try out tools such as `system-config-kickstart` whenever I need to do something which I have not done recently and then learn the needed format from there.

Comment: I already tried that, but I still don't understand how to set it up with that configurator either along with RAID 1 and no LVM. Also there is hardly any usable / updated information about that. I am now running a normal setup (with GUI) and do it that way to see how to KS file looks like.  Thanks though for the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well fixed it by giving it a go and using the following:

```
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1 --ondisk=sda
part biosboot --fstype=biosboot --size=1 --ondisk=sdb

part raid.01 --size=1024  --ondisk=sda
part raid.02 --size=10000 --ondisk=sda
part raid.03 --size=40768 --grow --ondisk=sda
part raid.04 --size=4096  --ondisk=sda

part raid.05 --size=1024  --ondisk=sdb
part raid.06 --size=10000 --ondisk=sdb
part raid.07 --size=40768 --grow --ondisk=sdb
part raid.08 --size=4096  --ondisk=sdb

raid /boot --level=RAID1 --device=md0 --fstype=ext4 raid.01 raid.05
raid /     --level=RAID1 --device=md1 --fstype=ext4 raid.02 raid.06
raid /vz   --level=RAID1 --device=md2 --fstype=ext4vz raid.03 raid.07
raid swap  --level=RAID1 --device=md3 --fstype=swap raid.04 raid.08
```

No clue if this correct, but apparently it works. I only wished someone could have provided some help with this. Oh well... Wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [`mdadm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm),

> mdadm - manage MD devices aka Linux Software RAID

See this answer for setting it up, [CentOS kickstart automated setup with parted / RAID](https://serverfault.com/q/633971/432466).